# bash- Control-C behavior (^C) / gksudo vs sudo

Tags: command-line, bash, sudo, gksudo

This is about how the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> key press has a different effect when performed to a `gksudo` instance as opposed to a `sudo` instance.

I executed the following using `gksudo` to read an installation failure log file:

```
$ gksudo gedit /tmp/vmware-root/setup-5686.log
```

When I meant to close the gedit instance, I alt-tabbed to the (originating) console and pressed <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>.  Control returned to the console BUT the `gedit` program was still running fine.

This is different behavior than how `sudo` behaves if used in the previous call (which I do NOT recommend doing).  By using `sudo`, ^C returns control to the console AND closes the `gedit` program.

I am new to Linux... is this normal behavior, and why?

Comment: I suspect it has more to do with whether gedit opens in standalone mode, or attaches to an already-open instance, than with differences in Ctrl-C behaviour.

Comment: I have a different perspective, coming from an AmigaDOS background.  In both cases the terminal prompt is locked to the '*sudo' call, shouldn't killing gksudo kill all child processes just like 'sudo'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the normal behaviour of a normal `gksudo`/`gksu`, at least on Xubuntu & Linux Mint XFCE. Killing (CTRL+C) `gksu gedit` (gksudo is a link to gksu) leaves gedit still running.

`man gksu` has this potentially useful info:

> Also
>          notice that the library will decide if it should use su or sudo as backend using
>          the  /apps/gksu/sudo-mode gconf key, if you call the gksu command. You can force
>          the backend by using the  gksudo  command,  or  by  using  the  --sudo-mode  and
>          --su-mode options.

But testing with either option results in the same behaviour.

---

This test might be enlightening:

```
$ gksu gedit
```

[then in another terminal]

```
$ ps -ef|grep [g]edit
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
mint      6878  6701  0 23:04 pts/0    00:00:00 gksu gedit
root      6879  6878  0 23:04 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/sudo -H -S -p GNOME_SUDO_PASS -u root -- gedit
root      6880  6879  0 23:04 ?        00:00:00 gedit
```

[After killing (CTRL+C) the `gksu gedit` in the first terminal, it doesn't stop `sudo` or `gedit`]

```
$ ps -ef|grep [g]edit
root      6879     1  0 23:04 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/sudo -H -S -p GNOME_SUDO_PASS -u root -- gedit
root      6880  6879  0 23:04 ?        00:00:00 gedit
```

[Killing the first `sudo` (with another sudo) does kill `gedit`]

```
$ sudo kill 6879
$ ps -ef|grep [g]edit
```

Just like running `sudo gedit` in a terminal will start `gedit`, and CTRL+C `sudo` will kill `gedit`. But also, if I close the terminal, `sudo` and `gedit` still keep running.

So, `sudo` doesn't care if the program that called it (`gksu` or a terminal) gets killed, it and whatever it's started keeps running too.

---

And these excerpts from `man sudo` might be helpful too:

> > Process model
> >          When sudo runs a command, it calls fork(2), sets up the execution environment as described above, and calls the execve system call in the child
> >          process.  The main sudo process waits until the command has completed,
> >          then passes the command's exit status to the security policy's close
> >          function and exits.
> >
> > Signal handling
> >          When the command is run as a child of the sudo process, sudo will relay
> >          signals it receives to the command.  Unless the command is being run in a
> >          new pty, the SIGHUP, SIGINT and SIGQUIT signals are not relayed unless
> >          they are sent by a user process, not the kernel.  Otherwise, the command
> >          would receive SIGINT twice every time the user entered control-C.  Some
> >          signals, such as SIGSTOP and SIGKILL, cannot be caught and thus will not
> >          be relayed to the command.  As a general rule, SIGTSTP should be used
> >          instead of SIGSTOP when you wish to suspend a command being run by sudo.